# How to remove Virtualbox "VirtualBox VMs" folder in /home directory?

Tags: virtualbox

I used the following commands in the terminal to remove VBOX from my PC. But the "Virtualbox VMs" folder remains in HOME of Ubuntu 12.04. How to completely remove this folder of VBOX ?

```
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-ose --purge
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox* --purge
sudo ./VirtualBox.run uninstall
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox* --purge
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-*
```

Replacing * with the version of VirtualBox installed on my system (e.g. `sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-4.2`).

```
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-\*
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-\*
```

Answer (score 3):

The folder you see are the virtual machines that you have used with virtualbox (the virtual HDs so to speak). You already have successfully uninstalled the software but you have to manually delete the virtual hard drives if you don't need them anymore.